# complexity for recursive functions (Big O notation)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have two functions which I would like to determine the complexity for.

The first one I just need to know whether my solving is correct, the second one because of the two recursive calls I am struggling to find the solution to, if possible would be good to have the working out so that I can learn how its done.

First:

```
def sum(list):
    assert len(list)>0
    if len(list) == 1:
        return list[0]
    else:
        return sum(list[0:-1]) + list[-1]
```

Attempted solution :

```
T(0) = 4
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 + c -- True for all n >0 

T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 + c
     = T(n-2) + 2 + 2C
     = T(n-k) + k = kC --(n-k = 0 implies that k=n)
T(n) = T(0) + n + nC
     = T(0) + 2nC --(T0 is nothing but 4)
     = 6nC
Complexity = O(n)
```

Second:

```
def binSum(list):
    if len(list) == 1:  
        return list[0]
    else:
        return binSum(list[:len(list)//2]) + binSum(list[len(list)//2:])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: How is `n+nc = n²c`? Also, first you write `T(0) = 4` and then "`T(0)` is nothing but 1". It does not change the result, but it is inconsistent. Maybe you want do tell us your guess on the second function.

Comment: Apologies for the errors, continuing on from T(n) = T(0) + n + nc:
=T(0) + 2nc -- (T) is nothing but 4)
=4+2nc 
=6+nc

COMPLEXITY O(n) ??

Comment: That's correct. You can edit this into your question. What about the second function?

Comment: I find it easier (generally and if possible which it almost always is) to convert the recursive function into a non-recursive one and then calculate the complexity. For your second question, try changing it to non-recursive loops and see what the complexity will be (I imagine it will be O(n Log(n)) but I haven't calculated it so I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you can model the time complexity with the recursive function `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)` and `T(0) = O(1)`. which obviously solves to `T(n) = O(n)`.

Here's a more direct and more formal proof by induction. The base case is easy: `T(0)<=C` by the definition of `O(1)`. For the inductive step, suppose that `T(k) <= C*k` for all `k<=n` for some absolute constant `C>0`. Now `T(n+1) <= D + T(n) <= D + C*n <= max(C,D)*(n+1)` by the inductive hypothesis, where `D>0` is an absolute constant.

For the second case, you can model the time complexity with `T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) = 2T(n/2)` for `n>1` and `T(1)=O(1)`. This solves to `T(n)=O(n)` by the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).